# libvirt rejects passthrough USB in XML

Tags: usb, xml, libvirt

On a Debian 10 machine, I have a KVM VM with Windows 10. It runs fine. The libvirt version is 5.0.0-4+deb10u1.

I want the VM to recognize a video camera that is attached to the Debian host via USB. Adding the following code to the XML file fails:

```
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
      <source startupPolicy='optional' guestReset='off'>
        <vendor id='0x04da'/>
        <product id='0x2497'/>
      </source>
    </hostdev>
```

**Error message**:

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Extra element devices in interleave
Element domain failed to validate content
```

The full XML file (including the offending code near the end) is below. The code is more or less verbatim from the [libvirt documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#usb-pci-scsi-devices).

What's wrong here? What's meant by "interleave"? Are there alternatives for checking the XML file that provide more insight?

**XML file**:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>Windows10</name>
  <uuid>90486b86-7fe0-4409-8e40-ee6d9ece3098</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-3.1'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>SandyBridge</model>
    <vendor>Intel</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pcid'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='arat'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tsc_adjust'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='umip'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xsaveopt'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdpe1gb'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/home/bbausch/Windows10.qcow2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:a9:ba:c4'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>

    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
      <source startupPolicy='optional' guestReset='off'>
        <vendor id='0x04da'/>
        <product id='0x2497'/>
      </source>
    </hostdev>

  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+64055:+64055</label>
    <imagelabel>+64055:+64055</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

libvirt documentation spells it out:

> Since 8.6.0, the source element can contain guestReset attribute with the following value:

Since I am using Libvirt 5, the `guestReset` attribute is not supported. After removing it, the XML file passes validation.

It would be great if the error message were a bit more descriptive.